# SAP UI5 - DatePicker gives an error after setting Min and Max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, sapui5

I have two DatePicker input fields called as "startDate" & "endDate".

When "startDate" is selected, it should set max value of "enddate" as `"startDate" + 180 days`. It should also set Min value of "endDate" as `"startDate"`

View is as below:

```
var oTableTopFilterForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.Form({
            editable: true,
            layout: new sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveLayout(),
            formContainers:[
                            new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer({
                                formElements:[



                                              new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                                                  label: new sap.m.Label({
                                                      text:"Start Date"
                                                  }),
                                                  fields:[
                                                          new sap.m.DatePicker("startDate",{
                                                              forceSelection: false,
                          enabled:false,
                          valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                          placeholder:"Choose Start Date ... ",
                                                              change:[oController.onStartDateSelect]
                                                          })                                  

                                                          ]
                                              }),   

                                              new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                                                  label: new sap.m.Label({
                                                      text:"EndDate"
                                                  }),
                                                  fields:[
                                                          new sap.m.DatePicker("endDate",{
                                                              forceSelection: false,
                         enabled:false,
                        placeholder:"Choose End Date ... ",
                                                              change:[]
                                                          })                                  

                                                          ]
                                              }),


                                              ]
                            })
                            ]
        }); // oTableTopFilterForm
```

onStartDateSelect function in the controller is as follow:

```
    var startdate = sap.ui.getCore().byId("startDate").getDateValue();

    var enddate = sap.ui.getCore().byId("endDate");
    enddate.setEnabled(true);

    var tempDate = new Date(startdate);
    var enddatemax = new Date(tempDate);
    enddatemax.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 180);  
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(enddatemax > currentDate)
    {
// This condition works fine
alert(enddatemax);
alert("End Date is bigger than Current Date");      
enddate.setMaxDate(currentDate);
enddate.setMinDate(startdate);

    }
    else
    {
    alert(enddatemax);
    alert("End Date is smaller than Current Date"); 
            enddate.setMinDate(startdate);
    enddate.setMaxDate(enddatemax);
    alert(enddate.getMinDate());
    alert(enddate.getMaxDate());
    }

}
```

No error is encountred till now. Last two alerts gives proper MinDate and MaxDate for endDate.

But now when I try to select endDate, it gives following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Date must not be in valid range (minDate and maxDate); Element sap.ui.unified.Calendar#endDate-cal
    at f.n (Calendar.js:6)
    at f.c.focusDate (Calendar.js:6)
    at f.a._fillDateRange (DatePicker.js:6)
    at f._ (DatePicker.js:6)
    at f.b (DatePicker.js:6)
    at f.a.onclick (DatePicker.js:6)
    at f.a._handleEvent (sap-ui-core.js:954)
    at constructor.U._handleEvent (sap-ui-core.js:1178)
    at HTMLDivElement.p (sap-ui-core.js:115)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (sap-ui-core.js:126)
```

Not sure why DatePicker is giving me an error when Min and Max dates are set properly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of SAPUI5 does this issue happen on, seems to work on 1.42